# Displaying complete host name when login to linux

Tags: hostname, bashrc

How can I display hostname along with user when I login to Linux machine? Now I can see only part of host name where I could not able to identify the server name. would like to display as below;
For example:

```
[centos@yourfullhostname]$
```

if changed to root then

```
[root@yourfullhostname]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the manual before asking the question?

```
PS1='[\u@\H]$ '
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in the Unix & Linux exchange already, but the answer is to add `PS1="\H$ "` to your /etc/bash.bashrc

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218174/how-to-show-the-host-name-in-linux-commandline-prompt

Comment: Assuming "yourfullhostname" means the FQDN, `\h` is incorrect; it should be `\H` instead.